# How to solve this equation in spherical coordinates

Tags: multivariable-calculus, spherical-coordinates

I am trying to find the angles $\phi$ that satisfy the following equation:
$$
\cos\phi + \sqrt{\cos^2\phi+15}=\frac{2}{\sin\phi},
$$
where $\phi \in [0,\pi ]$.

The geometric interpretation of this equation is the intersection between the sphere $x^2+y^2+(z-1)^2=16$ and the cylinder $x^2+y^2=4$.

To solve this, I have shifted the origin $1$ unit above $(0,0,0)$, in order for the sphere to be centered at the origin. Since the cylinder is infinitely long, the equation is than trivial, giving in this new basis angles $\pi/6$ and $5\pi/6$.

How can I solve the initial equation, or eventually find its solution from angles $\pi/6$ and $5\pi/6$?

Any other approach is welcomed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would write it as

$$
\sqrt{\cos^2\phi+15} = \frac{2}{\sin \phi} - \cos\phi
$$

Both left and right hand side are positive (where defined), so you can square both sides. You will get to

$$
\cos^2\phi + 15 = \frac{4}{\sin^2\phi} + \cos^2\phi - 4 \frac{\cos\phi}{\sin\phi}.$$

Cancel what you can, multiply by $\sin^2\phi$, and use [double angle formulas](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Double-AngleFormulas.html) to get everything in terms of $\sin 2\phi$ and $\cos 2\phi$.

If you want to see more steps done, read further.

After canceling and multiplying by $\sin^2\phi$ you get

$$
15\sin^2\phi + 4\cos\phi\sin\phi - 4 = 0
$$

Using double-angle formulas, you get

$$
15\frac{1-\cos 2\phi}{2} + 2\sin 2\phi -4 = 0.
$$

Hence

$$
15\cos 2\phi + 4\sin 2\phi +7 = 0.
$$

From here, you have to solve a linear equation in the unknown $2\phi$. This kind of equation can be solved following a recipe, as explained [here](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Trigonometry/Solving_Trigonometric_Equations#a_sin_x_.2B_b_cos_x_.3D_c).

Answer (score 2):

(BIG) HINT:

$$\cos(\phi)+\sqrt{\cos^2(\phi)+15}=\frac{2}{\sin(\phi)}\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$\cos(\phi)+\sqrt{\cos^2(\phi)+15}=2\csc(\phi)\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$\sqrt{\cos^2(\phi)+15}=2\csc(\phi)-\cos(\phi)\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$\cos^2(\phi)+15=\left(2\csc(\phi)-\cos(\phi)\right)^2\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$\cos^2(\phi)+15=\cos^2(\phi)-4\cot(\phi)+4\csc^2(\phi)\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$15+4\cot(\phi)-4\csc^2(\phi)=0\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$11+4\cot(\phi)-4\cot^2(\phi)=0\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$-\frac{11}{4}-\cot(\phi)+\cot^2(\phi)=0\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$\cot^2(\phi)-\cot(\phi)=\frac{11}{4}\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$\left(\cot(\phi)-\frac{1}{2}\right)^2=3\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$\cot(\phi)-\frac{1}{2}=\pm\sqrt{3}\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$\cot(\phi)=\pm\sqrt{3}+\frac{1}{2}\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$\cot(\phi)=\frac{1}{2}\pm\sqrt{3}$$

Comment: I think the spirit is right, but there seems to be an error somewhere: Maple gives me angles $\arctan(-2/11+(4/11)\sqrt{3})$ and $\arctan(-2/11+(4/11)\sqrt{3})+\pi$. But thanks, thats definitely what I'm looking for.

Comment: @Kuifje:  If $\cot \phi = \frac{1}{2} \pm \sqrt{3}$, then $$ \tan \phi = \frac{2}{1 \pm 2\sqrt{3}} = \frac{2(1 \mp 2 \sqrt{3})}{(1 \pm 2\sqrt{3})(1 \mp 2\sqrt{3})} = \frac{2 \mp 4 \sqrt{3}}{-11},$$ which agrees with your Maple results exactly.

Comment: You can also get this result from flawr's geometric method. See my comment on that answer.

Answer (score 1):

As the whole situation has a rotational symmetry w.r.t. to $z$ we can simplify the problem by looking at a plane which goes throu the z-axis.

In this image you can see that $R=4$ is the radius of the sphere, $r=2$ is the radius of the cylinder. You can also see that the intersectins are circles. And In this case you can easily find that those circles have radius $2$, and are (via pythagoras) at $z=\sqrt{R^2-r^2}\pm 1$.

[image]

Comment: The sphere has radius 4, the cylinder 2. And the intersection of $x^2+y^2+(z-1)^2=16, x^2+y^2=4$ is at $z=1+\sqrt{12}$.

Comment: Your picture is not right: the sphere does not have a radius that equals 4.

Comment: Yes it is, the sphere has the equation $x^2+y^2+(z-1)^2 = 16 = R^2$. Therefore $R=4$.

Comment: In your picture, $R  >4$.

Comment: Oh, that is what you mean, yes it really seems that the radius is somewhat of, but it is rather like $R=4.2$. I'll update it!

Comment: And how can you find angles $\phi$ from this?

Comment: How is $\phi$ defined?

Comment: Note that whereas this figure explicitly shows the triangle $\triangle AIG$ with legs $2$ and $\sqrt{12} = 2\sqrt3$, if you define the label $O=(0,0)$ there is also $\triangle OIG$ with legs $2$ and $1 + 2\sqrt3$. If, as I suspect, the angle $\phi$ you want at $G$ is $\angle IOG$, then you immediately have $\tan \phi = \frac{2}{1 + 2\sqrt3}$. For the other points of intersection (where $z<0$) you can construct a right triangle with one leg along the negative $z$-axis and find that $\tan(\pi-\phi) = \frac{2}{-1 + 2\sqrt3}$, so $\tan\phi = \frac{2}{1 - 2\sqrt3}$.